# jQuery .contains(+number+)

Tags: javascript, jquery

it's been a long day and I think I just have code blindness but..

Trying to figure out if an element contains a number, do something to another element.

```
result_val = 9;

$(".result").contains("+result_val+") (function() {
    $(".parag").css("color", "#eee");
});
```

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach? But there is no effect on the `.parag` div.

http://jsfiddle.net/xzeCq/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
result_val = 9;

if($(".result:contains(" + result_val + ")").length > 0 )
{
  $(".parag").css("color", "#eee");   
}
```

Or to get a boolean

```
result_val = 9;

if($(".result").is(":contains(" + result_val + ")") )
{
  $(".parag").css("color", "#eee");   
}
```

Live DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xzeCq/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
result_val = 9;
text=$(".result").html();

if(text == result_val)
{
    $(".parag").css("color", "#eee");
}
```

refer this : http://jsfiddle.net/xzeCq/6/